# Compare two string variables in bash shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix

The output I get is 
sh21.sh: 5: [: xhi: unexpected operator
no match

My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="hi"
s2="hi"
s3="hello"
if [ "x$s1" == "x$s2" ]
then
  echo match
else
  echo no match
fi
```

Please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I executed this and it matches. I dont see the problem, may be you are not executing this with bash shell?

Comment: There is only **ONE** `=` in POSIX test construct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what is the POSIX test construct? `test` is a program.

Comment: It is a keyword. When you type `test` or `[` in a shell, you are telling the shell to test what follows. (I think `[` is actually an alias of `test`) POSIX shell is just that subset of features that is more or less guaranteed to work with *every* shell. Things like `[[` are referred to as *Bashisms* because they only work with bash and are not guaranteed to be portable between shells. **Oh**, and yes I see what you are saying, `test` is a program along with all the others that make up the shell. When I say construct, I just mean what the shell uses.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use bashisms in your script, it is important to use bash.  Your code works fine with bash:

```
$ bash sh21.sh
match
```

It fails with dash (which is the `sh` on debian-like systems):

```
$ sh sh21.sh
sh21.sh: 5: [: xhi: unexpected operator
no match
```

`==` is a bashism, meaning it only works under bash or similar shells.  If you want a POSIX compatible script, use `=`.  If not, run the script under bash.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ "x$s1" == "x$s2" ]
```

should be

```
if [ "x$s1" = "x$s2" ]
```

There is only 1 equal sign when using `test` or `[` in shell programming. Bash allows `==` with `[[`, but it should not be used with `[`. Both `test` and `[` are equivalent and are the POSIX test utility. Bash has the `[[` operator that is *not* the same. There are subtle differences in syntax, quoting requirements and available operators between them.

Comment: The shebang line says `/bin/bash` and Bash actually tolerates `==` with `[` as well.  I'm guessing the OP incorrectly runs the script with `sh scriptname`., though.

Comment: Yes I saw that, and you're right, but then I thought it better to start out with the rule rather than muddying the water with all the exceptions that bash allows. I don't think I can type that long...

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "construct". There is absolutely *no* special handling with either `test` or `[` that doesn't apply to any other program. (In fact, there is no requirement for `test` or `[` to even be a built-in command; both probably exist in your file system.)

Comment: Bad choice of words. `utility` -- fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using Debian based distros, and the default shell is **dash**, not **bash**

Check your shell

```
ls -l /bin/sh /bin/bash
```

Run the script with **bash**

```
bash sh21.sh
```